# I need mentoring while developing web based micro finance application

Tags: php, use-case, oop

I have been tasked to develop a web based micro finance (small loans for small groups) application. I will need someone to mentor me while I do this as this is the biggest application I have ever been asked to come up with. I am mostly self taught and have always worked alone however i feel this may be a good chance to step up my game so to speak.

I have below the highest level Actors and their Goals that I can think of at the moment and am aming to use agile development methodology hence I will be starting coding, and refining the use cases as I go along.

```
***Actor    Goal***
**Borrower** Request registration 
            Request to borrow
            Check Loan Account balance
            Check repayment history
            Make early repayment
            Request to Switch groups

**Loan Officer** Pre-register group
             Record daily borrower repayments /collections
             Generate expected daily collection

**Saver**  Request registration 
             Check Account balance
             Check deposit history

**Loan Administrator** Assess borrower
             Register borrower
             Approve pending borrower registration
             Get following weeks budget
             Generate default list
             Manage borrowers
             Manage borrower details
             Manage staff
             Generate new loan projection
             Manage loans
             Manage savings accounts

  **System Administrator** Modify system settings
             Manage system parameters
             Approve exception loan amount request

 **Amortization System** Calculate loan repayment schedule
 **Borrower Assessment System** Determine maximum loan amount for borrower
 **Savings System** Credit savings account
                    Debit savings account
                    Create savings account
```

I have decided to have 5 modules in the system ie Loan Module, Savings Module, Loan Administrator Module, Defaul Module and System Administrator Module this is to help me apart from segregating the application also it will help me control access to functionalily better i think.

I am now going to do the use case for what i call the base goals like the various registrations and logins.

cheers

Comment: Any specific questions so far?

Comment: You should identify questions you have about this. it's too opened ended.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are on the right path. Far better direction than I had on my first big project. Extend the same organized process to the code and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks all, i guess you are right about the question being too open ended. I will continue and when I get stuck I will come back. I guess i was looking gor general pointers but thanks anyway guys. I'll be back